# Why doesn't the child form appear on the same screen as the parent form?

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, handle, multiple-monitors

**Update**

I accepted Rufus L's answer with a few mods, Relevant code follows

```
public partial class ClsOfficeRibbonFooTab
{

    private void FooTab_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
         .
         .
         .
    }

    private void CheckResolution()
    {
        // set the left position so that the expanded version of the form fits on the screen
        Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd));

        if (screen.Bounds.Width < 1360 || screen.Bounds.Height < 768)
        {
            throw new FormatException(String.Format("The {0} is supported on screens with a resolution of 1360 by 768 or greater. Your screen is {1} by {2}", "Some caption text", screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height));
        }
    }

    private void ObjButtonFoo_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ClsFormFoo objFormFoo = new ClsFormFoo(parentWindow: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow))
        {
            CheckResolution();
            objFormFoo.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

public partial class ClsFormFoo : Form
{
    // This form is a fixed dialog with a flyout on the right side. 
    // expandedWidth is a const set to the max width of this fixed dialog (i.e., the dialog with the flyout extended)
    const int expandedWidth = 1345;

    public ClsFormFoo(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window parentWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Top = parentWindow.Top;
    }

    private void ClsFormFoo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd));

        // set the left position so that the expanded version of the form fits on the screen for all legal resolutions
        int halfScreenWidth = (int)(screen.WorkingArea.Width / 2);
        // This form is a fixed dialog with a flyout on the right side. 
        // expandedWidth is a const set to the max width of this fixed dialog (i.e., the dialog with the flyout extended)
        int halfFormWidth = (int)(expandedWidth / 2);
        this.Left = screen.Bounds.Left + ((int)(halfScreenWidth - halfFormWidth));
    }
}
```

**Original Post**

My `VSTO Add-In` provides a ribbon button that when clicked, calls `ObjButtonFoo_Click`, which in turn, shows a `ClsFormFoo` form (See **Code** below). `ObjButtonFoo_Click` includes code to create an IWin32Window owner value representative of Word to pass to ShowDialog.

On a multiple-monitor setup, I would expect that `objFormFoo` would appear on the same monitor on which Word itself is displayed. However, when I bring up Word on a secondary monitor and cause `ObjButtonFoo_Click` to be executed, `objFormFoo` appears on the Primary monitor

What do I do to make `objFormFoo` appear on the same monitor that Word itself is displayed on whether its the primary monitor or not?

Note: I verified that winWordMain is populated, i.e., its not null. See **winWordMain** below

**Code**

```
private void ObjButtonFoo_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    NativeWindow winWordMain = new NativeWindow();
    winWordMain.AssignHandle(new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd));
    IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd);

    using (ClsFormFoo objFormFoo = new ClsFormFoo()
    {
        objFormFoo.ShowDialog(winWordMain);
    }

    winWordMain.ReleaseHandle();
}
```

**winWordMain**

[image]

Comment: What do you expect if Word is streched across multiple monitors? Do you just want to center your form over Word? Or are you trying to detect a monitor?

Comment: @RufusL: Can't remember where I saw it, but I think I read that if an app is across monitors, Windows will report that the app is on the monitor that has the majority of the app's window on it. In any case, I want the form to be centered on the screen that Windows reports the app is on. My updated code (based on your answer) accomplishes this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have VSTO to test this, but it seems to me that you could just get the position of the `ActiveWindow` that you're using as the parent, and then use that as a reference for positioning your child form:

```
private void allRootsWithChilds_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var winWordMain = new NativeWindow();
    var parent = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow;
    winWordMain.AssignHandle(new IntPtr(parent.Hwnd));

    using (var objFormFoo = new ClsFormFoo())
    {
        // Set the Left and Top properties so this form is centered over the parent
        objFormFoo.Left = parent.Left + (parent.Width - objFormFoo.Width) / 2;
        objFormFoo.Top = parent.Top + (parent.Height - objFormFoo.Height) / 2;

        objFormFoo.ShowDialog(winWordMain);
    }

    winWordMain.ReleaseHandle();
}
```

Comment: See **Update** in my op.

Comment: There is no need to do any math calculations.

Comment: Isn't the `StartPosition` property made for exactly for such purposes?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The `Form` has a flyout. I need to calculate left/top using the worst case (1345 pixels wide) so when the form first appears (900 pixels wide) it will still fit on the screen when the flyout appears. Also, the app supports screen resolutions 1360x768-1920x1080. `StartPostion` in my case is `Manual`, i,e,, I don't want or need Windows positioning my form. See [Form.StartPosition Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.startposition?view=netframework-4.8) for more info regarding `StartPostion`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `StartPosition` property of your form to the `FormStartPosition.CenterParent` value:

```
loginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
loginForm.ShowDialog(parentWindowdle);
```

Comment: I also assumed that passing the parent window handle to the child form would make the child form "follow" the parent, but that's not true. Your code makes the child form center on the parent when the Word app is on the primary screen, but when the Word app is on the secondary screen, the child form still appears on the primary screen (centered on the screen)

Comment: Did Word start on the primary screen?

Comment: As I said in my first reply: Your code makes the child form center on the parent when the Word app is on the primary screen, but when the Word app is on the secondary screen, the child form still appears on the primary screen (centered on the screen)

Answer (score 0):

I used to make a simple screensaver on C#. I used the following code to open the screensaver on the desired screen or on all of them.

You have to take `bounds` from the desired screen and pass it to the form.

```
// Constructor
public NameForm(Rectangle bounds)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Bounds = bounds;
}

// In my case, this is opening the screensaver on all screens
foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    NameForm form = new NameForm (screen.Bounds);
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Maybe its because I'm using `ShowDialog(IWin32Window object)` and/or because it's a VSTO add-in and the parent in this case is the Word application, but your approach didn't work. I made the changes you suggested and when I have Word on the secondary monitor, `objFormFoo` continues to appear on the primary monitor. Also, my explicit width and height settings for objFormFoo (It's a `FixedDialog`) are ignored and objFormFoo is displayed with a width and height that I can't explain

Comment: @NovaSysEng I will try this myself and say you result

Comment: My bad - I forgot that in my `ClsFormFoo` code, I modify the `Left' property myself for centering based on screen resolution. When I used your code and commented my code out,  `objFormFoo` appeared on the same screen as Word itself. However, the ClsFormFoo height setting that I established in the designer was over-written with the `Height` setting from parent screen Bounds object passed in. For this reason, I have to go with Rufus L's solution. It modifies only the properties needed to move `objFormFoo` to the same screen as the parent.

Comment: @NovaSysEng try set `StartPosition` for `Form` to `Manual`. Since `bounds` contains the size of the screen, the `form` will be opened to the full screen. You need to change this yourself. As well as the starting position (`Location`). Starting from the bounds of the desired screen.